# Forcing ".png" in JFileChooser Save Dialog

Tags: java, swing, jfilechooser

I'm trying to get an automatic .png behind the Filename in the `JFileChooser`.

How can I accomplish that?

```
public class Capture {

  public static BufferedImage getScreenShot(Component component) {
    BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(component.getWidth(), component.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
    component.paint(image.getGraphics());
    return image;
  }

  public static void getSaveSnapShot(Component component, String fileName) throws Exception {
    BufferedImage img = getScreenShot(component);

    JFileChooser jfc = new JFileChooser();
    jfc.addChoosableFileFilter(new FileNameExtensionFilter("Image files",new String[] { "png" }));
    int retVal = jfc.showSaveDialog(null);

    if(retVal==JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
      File f = jfc.getSelectedFile();
      String test = f.getAbsolutePath();
      ImageIO.write(img,"png",new File(test));
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just check if the path ends with png. If not add it:

```
...
String test = f.getAbsolutePath();
if (!test.endsWith(".png")) {
    test = test + ".png";
}
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You also have the option to add a filter to allow only some kind of files.

```java
fileChooser.addChoosableFileFilter(new FileNameExtensionFilter("Images", "jpg", "png", "gif", "bmp"));
fileChooser.addChoosableFileFilter(new FileNameExtensionFilter("*.pdf", "pdf"));
fileChooser.addChoosableFileFilter(new FileNameExtensionFilter("*.txt", "txt"));
```

That can help if you want to be sure to not have corrupted file when adding manually their type.